# Override class in external swf

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem with a 3rd party component (lets call it X) that loads another 3rd party component swf (lets call it Y). But Y has a bug when used with X, which I need to fix.

X loads Y using:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListerner(Event.Complete, this.onLoadCom);
loader.load(new URLRequest(config.path));
addChild(loader);
...
private function onLoadCom(event:Event) {
   this.swf = event.target.content;
   addChild(this.swf);
   this.swf.blabla.connect();
}
```

as it is, I have the option of specifying another `config.path`, and thus load another file.
But I have no idea how I can make a swf Y2 that can be loaded instead of the original file without any changes to X and still keep the same api.

Once I figure out how to do that, I also need to figure out a second thing:

In order to fix the bug, I must call a function in X during the initialization of Y, I have a good guess this can be done using `getDefinitionByName`, but is unclear how I deal with the application domains.

Comment: Instead of trying to fix it at runtime, I would suggest you recompile fixed versions of X and Y, if you have access to the source. Otherwise you may need to edit the bytecodes in the original swfs.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to source

Comment: Without access to the source this would be difficult, maybe you can decompile the swfs but even then you may not be able to do what you need.